# JavaScript/V8: Making a custom `.then` method compatible with async stack traces

Tags: node.js, async-await, v8, stack-trace

Recent versions of V8 have "async stack traces", which means you get good stack traces even across async gaps if you use native `async`/`await`.

I'm trying to figure out how to get good stack traces when I'm `await`ing on a custom object with a `.then` method, rather than on a Promise.

```js
"use strict";

function gap() {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1));
}

// A class that has it's own 'then' method.
class Blah {
    constructor(f) {
        this.f = f;
    }
    then(onFulfilled, onRejected) {
        this.f()
            .then(r => onFulfilled ? onFulfilled(r) : r)
            .catch(onRejected);
    }
}

async function f3() {
    await gap();
    const blah = new Blah(async () => { throw new Error('blah'); });
    await blah;
}
async function f2() {
    await gap();
    await f3();
}
async function f1() {
    await gap();
    await f2();
}
async function mainAsync() {
    try {
        await f1();
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('err', err);
    }
}

if (require.main === module) {
    mainAsync().catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
    });
}
```

The stack trace I get in Node 14.15.0 and Chrome 88.0.4324.150 doesn't have a good stack trace:

```
err Error: blah
    at Blah.f (main.js:21:47)
    at Blah.then (main.js:13:14)
```

If I throw the exception directly from `f3()`, I get a good stack trace:

```
err Error: blah
    at f3 (main.js:19:11)
    at async f2 (main.js:24:5)
    at async f1 (main.js:28:5)
    at async mainAsync (main.js:32:9)
```

Is there a way to write the custom `.then` method so that I get a good stack trace?

**Why I want to do this**

The custom object is actually from a 3rd-party DB query library, [Mammoth](https://github.com/Ff00ff/mammoth).  Mammoth provides a fluent-style API to build a query, e.g. `db.select(...).from(...)`.

To then run the query, you `await` the query object.  (The query object has a custom `.then`: [code link](https://github.com/Ff00ff/mammoth/blob/144b46482608f9c1582f33832e234e2b6dfda2fc/src/select.ts#L155).)

I'm trying to modify Mammoth to yield good stack traces without changing Mammoth's public API.

Comment: What purpose does this `then()` function serve that a function that returns a normal `Promise` or is `async` wouldn't do just the same? A constructor isn't supposed to be `async` either, but you can have a factory method that is, like `await thing.ready` where `this.ready` is your promise established in the constructor.

Comment: @tadman: Good question.  I updated my question with an explanation of why I'm doing things this way.

Comment: Could you wrap these using a function that converts them to actual promises? `function promisify(x) { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { x.then(resolve) } }` for example.

Comment: It would be better if they could just get with the program and use Promises. There's a lot of pre-Promises/A+ code out there that does things in a variety of wonky and weird ways, which at the time made sense, but now is just sloppy.

Comment: My current workaround involves wrapping every query, e.g. replacing `await db.select(...).from(...)` with `await wrap(db.select(...).from(...))`.  The `wrap` function is something that fixes the stack trace.  I'm looking for something less tedious.

Comment: If it were just a single function, then I could just wrap it once.  The problem is that `db.select(...)` returns an object that you might then call `.from(...)` on, which returns an object that might you might then call `.where(...)` on.  When any of those objects are `await`ed is when the query actually executes.

Comment: I wouldn't put Mammoth in the category of old libraries that do things in old ways.  It's quite recent and does use promises internally.  I think the `.then` thing is intentional usability decision to make things less verbose.  If there's a better way to achieve the same API (query object executes when `await`ed), I imagine the author would be open to it.

Comment: Whatever the case, having a `then()` function but not being an actual Promise is nothing if not strange. It impedes utility as you're demonstrating here.